# How to use dispatch in nextjs getStaticprops or getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, serverside-javascript

I am new to Next js, I want to call the news api in `useEffect` and dispatch the news array to my store. then filter it based on the user's input in the search bar in the header. problem is once the use effect data fetching is done and user starts typing rather than filtering the news array the screen gets re-render and the data fetching starts again. how to prevent this re-rendering and save the news array?

I tried to use `getStaticprops`  but useDispatch is not allowed in there.

`index.js`

```
import { fetchNews } from "../store/actions/newsActions";
import NewsInfo from "../components/NewsInfo";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";

export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { news } = useSelector((state) => state.news);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchNews());
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {/* this wrapper cmp will make each headline uniquely accessible  */}
      {news?.articles ? (
        news.articles.map((article) => (
          <React.Fragment key={article.publishedAt}>
            <NewsInfo headlines={article} />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))
      ) : (
        <CircularProgress />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

`Header.js`

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import InputBase from "@material-ui/core/InputBase";
import { fade, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { filterHeadlines } from "../store/actions/newsActions";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    display: "none",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      display: "block",
    },
  },
  search: {
    position: "relative",
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "auto",
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: "inherit",
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch",
      },
    },
  },
}));

function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
            Material-UI
          </Typography>
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
              value={input}
              onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
              onBlur={() => dispatch(filterHeadlines(input))}
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
export default SearchAppBar;
```

Comment: Could you share the implementation of the Header/SearchBar?

Comment: @Hangindev I added the header

Comment: this is embarrassing I was filtering the whole array rather than finding the element

Answer (score 0):

you can use store dispatch to getServersideProps, getstaticprops

from your store file

export const rootDispatch = store.dispatch;